# Is it possible to add index to mysql with multiple column to optimize order by performance?

Tags: mysql, index, sorting

```
  # I have a simple table
  create table t1 (c1 int, c2 int);
  # I want to do the following sorting
  select * from t1 order by c2 desc, c1 desc;
  select * from t1 order by c2 asc, c1 desc;
  # add indexs
  CREATE INDEX index_1 ON t1 (c1 DESC, c2 DESC);  
  CREATE INDEX index_2 ON t1 (c1 ASC, c2 DESC);  
  # then explain
  explain select * from t1 order by c2 desc, c1 desc;
  # the result is
  mysql> explain select * from t1 order by c2 desc, c1 asc;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | NULL          | index_2 | 10      | NULL |    6 | Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My questions are

1. Are the indexs optimized the performance?
2. Why **Using index; Using filesort** show at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an index on `(c2, c1)` for this query, not an index on `(c1, c2)`.

Of course it would be best if there was an index `(c2 DESC, c1 DESC)` for the first and an index `(c2 DESC, c1 ASC)` for the second query. Unfortunately MySQL cannot create such indexes. The `ASC` and `DESC` are ignored.

Which means your two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_1 ON t1 (c1 DESC, c2 DESC);  
CREATE INDEX index_2 ON t1 (c1 ASC, c2 DESC);
```

are actually identical and same as if you had defined them as:

```
 CREATE INDEX c1_c2_index ON t1 (c1 ASC, c2 ASC);
```

---

If the performance - with the `(c2, c1)` index - is not good enough, you have a few options:

- Since the columns are of integer type, add two more columns and store the negative values. You'll need triggers to polulate those columns.

.

```
CREATE TABLE 
( c1 INT
, c2 INT
, c1_neg INT
, c2_neg INT
);
```

Then you can an indexes on `(c2_neg, c1)` and `(c2_neg, c1_neg)`

- If you can move to MariaDB, you can use [`VIRTUAL PERSISENT`](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/virtual-columns) columns and appropriate indexes for a similar solution (a bit better as you won't have to add triggers, the columns will be populated automatically).